# Which of the \dots_ variants go with \times?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, ellipsis, mathematics

Assume you write stuff such as

```
f\colon A_1 \times \dots \times A_n \to A_{n+1}
```

which declares a function `f` taking n arguments of types `A_1` till `A_n`, respectively, and returning a single value of type `A_{n+1}`. The printout is, roughly,

> f: A₁ × ⋯ × Aₙ → Aₙ₊₁

with somewhat more pleasant spacing around different symbols and Latin letters in italics.

We know that the AMS macro `\dots` tries to automatize the typesetting of a visually pleasant, "correct" ellipsis. Now, if you wish to do it manually (e.g., because you have some formatting commands packaging all the symbols, or because you wish to have a semantically richer document), which kind of ellipsis is supposed to be used here: `\dotsm` or `\dotsb`?

Comment: If the `amsmath` package is loaded, you'll get the same output with either `\dotsm` or `\dotsb` in the code snippet you posted. I assume it's the case because the multiplicative operator `\times` is of type `mathbin`.

Comment: I honestly don't know. I suppose somebody (not me, for sure!) might come with the idea, one fine day, that `\times` should no longer be of type `mathbin`.

Comment: You just use `\dots` that, by default, will typeset centered dots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf) (section **4.3 Dots**):

> For preferred placement of ellipsis dots (raised or on-line) in various contexts there is no general consensus. It may therefore be considered a matter of taste. By using the semantically oriented commands
>
> - `\dotsc` for "dots with commas"
> - `\dotsb` for "dots with binary operators/relations"
> - `\dotsm` for "multiplication dots"
> - `\dotsi` for "dots with integrals"
> - `\dotso` for "other dots" (none of the above)
>
> instead of `\ldots` and `\cdots`, [...]

As such, if you wish to manually use a `\dots_` specification, then `\dotsb` would be used in your case, since `\times` is a binary relation. `\dotsm` would be used if you dropped `\times` and used

```
f \colon A_1 \dots A_n \to A_{n+1}
```

and `\dots` should represent an implicit multiplication between elements `A_1` through `A_n`.

Here's a visual of the different uses:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\verb|\dots |:  $f \colon A_1 \times \dots \times A_n \to A_{n+1}$

\verb|\dotsb|: $f \colon A_1 \times \dotsb \times A_n \to A_{n+1}$

\verb|\dotsm|: $f \colon A_1 \times \dotsm \times A_n \to A_{n+1}$

\verb|\dots |:  $f \colon A_1 \dots A_n \to A_{n+1}$

\verb|\dotsb|: $f \colon A_1 \dotsb A_n \to A_{n+1}$

\verb|\dotsm|: $f \colon A_1 \dotsm A_n \to A_{n+1}$

\end{document}
```

It's clear that `\dotsb` and `\dotsm` result in similar output - [they are both `\let` to `\cdots`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427290/which-of-the-dots-variants-go-with-times/427295?noredirect=1#comment1069132_427295). However, in different contexts, `\dots` print differently.

Comment: the only problem is, `\dotsm` is functionally equivalent to `\dotsb`, and in fact both are `\let` to `\cdots`.  i think that the "extra" name (which i assume to be `dotsm`) is provided because the `m` provides a mental jog for "mutiplication".  (i've checked the documentation for ams-tex, which is where `amsmath` inherited the names from.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: True. Printing with `\dots`, `\dotsb` or `\dotsm` provides the same output. If you force yourself to use them with their names in mind, I guess you could redefine them if need be.

Comment: @Werner Can I ask you a favor kindly? Could you put an image of an example so I understand what the question is? Since I do not publish the answers and the questions of the best there is a small mistake. Instead of `\lodts` there must be `\ldots`. +1